# UIImage memory leak with ARC & Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm receiving memory leaks and eventually a low memory warning while working on an application which needs to cycle through many large images in response to a user dragging onscreen.  In order to do this I'm updating each change with a new image via the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *rotationView;
.
.
.
// Update the displayed image to the specified image index.  Loads one image at
// a time and lets ARC handle release of old images.
-(void) displayNewImage:(int)imageIndex {
    // Initialize rotation image string (to be used when loading the image)
    NSMutableString *rotationImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [rotationImage setString:[self rotationImagePrefix]];
    [rotationImage appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d",imageIndex]];

    [self.rotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:rotationImage]];
}
```

I've found similar posts which state there is a known memory leak using +[UIImage imageNamed:] and recommend using +[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] however neither approach seems to affect performance positively.  Testing with +[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] actually saw a significant increase in memory leaks.

[image]
This was when using imageNamed.  Each malloc instance in the drop-down is another instance of a 7.00 KB reference.  Using imageWithContentsOfFile saw these leaks quadruple for the same test, telling me that imageWithContents is not caching the contents and instead creating new instances each time, which was expected.  One question here is how to then release this image next cycle when a new image needs to be created.

All similar questions I've found seem to confirm that this is a known memory leak within the ImageIO library.  Are there proven fixes for this, or is this pretty much we're stuck with what Apple provides as part of their UI framework, bugs and all?